# column exists but not showing

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created the following database..

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("create table ITEMS(ROW_ID integer primary key autoincrement,ITEM_DESCRIPTION text,ITEM_AMOUNT integer," +
            "time DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE);");
    db.execSQL("create table payments(PAY_ID integer primary key autoincrement,PAY_DESC text,PAY_AMT integer,date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE);");
}
```

and I am using the following function to retrieve payments table entries

```
public Cursor getPayments(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from " + KEY_PTABLE, null);
    for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
        c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("pay_id");
    }
    return c;
}
```

and the logcat is showing--

```
AndroidRuntime(30868): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
**AndroidRuntime(30868): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.expensesdatabase/com.example.expensesdatabase.PayView}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'pay_id' does not exist**
AndroidRuntime(30868): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
AndroidRuntime(30868): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
AndroidRuntime(30868): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
AndroidRuntime(30868): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
AndroidRuntime(30868): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
AndroidRuntime(30868): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
AndroidRuntime(30868): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
AndroidRuntime(30868): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
AndroidRuntime(30868): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
AndroidRuntime(30868): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
AndroidRuntime(30868): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
AndroidRuntime(30868): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
**AndroidRuntime(30868): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'pay_id' does not exist**
AndroidRuntime(30868): at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:267)
AndroidRuntime(30868): at com.example.expensesdatabase.MySQLiteHelper.getPayments(MySQLiteHelper.java:152)
```

Comment: table name .. that is payments

Comment: Are those fields are defined as Constant?

Comment: If you recently modified the table schema, did you remember to delete the old database file so that `onCreate()` gets called again?

Comment: @laalto This may the reason. Yes he should check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you recently modified the table schema, delete the old database file so that `onCreate()` gets called again.

Answer (score 1):

`PAY_ID` is not the same as `pay_id`

You must use the correct casing.

Answer (score 0):

Write `PAY_ID` in capital like this.

```
c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("PAY_ID");
```

Also change your query as

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from payments", null);
```

Comment: Also change your query as `Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from payments", null);`

Comment: why dont you write it in answer instead of comment ?

Comment: I am waiting for my answer to ready for update. My internet is working slow. @Kitkat

Answer (score 0):

Your error suggests that column does not exists.

Try this:

```
public Cursor getPayments(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c=db.query("payments", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    while(c.moveToNext())
    {
        // You can log the recieved data
        // Log.i("PAY_ID",c.getString(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("PAY_ID"))));
    }
    return c;
}
```